# how to spy on a function

Tags: javascript, sinon, spy

I am trying to spy on a global function e.g.

```
function foo() {

}
```

but the below test is failing, how to do that

```
    var spy = sinon.spy(foo);
    foo();
    expect(spy.callCount).to.equal(1);
```

** EDIT **

If I do it like below then it works

```
    var spy = sinon.spy(window, "foo");
    foo();
    expect(spy.callCount).to.equal(1);
```

So whats the difference

Comment: I've left an answer, if there is anything you would like for me to clarify please let me know. If the problem is resolve, indicate so by marking as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `var spy = sinon.spy(foo);` doesn't wrap the function `foo` as you might think. It actually returns a spy that contains the **wrapped** function.

Using `var spy = sinon.spy(window, "foo");` actually wraps the `foo` method. Internally, `window["foo"] = <wrapped function>` is being done, thus replacing your the function referenced by `foo` to the wrapped function.

For `var spy = sinon.spy(foo);` to work you must not call `foo()` instead you need to call `spy()`

```js
function foo() {

}

console.log('BEGIN sinon.spy(foo)');
var spy = sinon.spy(foo);
spy();
foo(); // called foo, but no effect on callCount
foo(); // called foo, but no effect on callCount
foo(); // called foo, but no effect on callCount
console.log('Call Count:', spy.callCount);

console.log('BEGIN sinon.spy(window, \'foo\')');
var spy = sinon.spy(window, 'foo');
spy();
foo(); 
foo(); 
foo();
console.log('Call Count:', spy.callCount);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sinon.js/1.15.4/sinon.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. btw, why not `window.foo` and why `window, "foo"`

Comment: the `spy` function needs to know the object and the method of that object to spy on. As I said in my answer, internally it is doing something like `object[method] = wrapped(object[method])` In javascript, you technically can't overwrite a function, but rather you redirect the reference of the function. The function referenced by `foo` is never changed, but the function referenced by the variable `foo` is changed, i.e. by the use of the object and method of the object.

Comment: thanks a lot for great explanation.. that nailed it for me :)